# UIView shake animation

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, cocoa-touch, core-animation

i'm trying to make a UIView shake when a button is pressed.

I am adapting the code I found on http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/27/core-animation-tutorial-window-shake-effect/.

However, by trying to adapt the following code to shake a UIView, it does not work:

```
- (void)animate {
    const int numberOfShakes = 8;
    const float durationOfShake = 0.5f;
    const float vigourOfShake = 0.1f;

    CAKeyframeAnimation *shakeAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];

    CGRect frame = lockView.frame;

    CGMutablePathRef shakePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(shakePath, NULL, CGRectGetMinX(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame));

    for (int index = 0; index < numberOfShakes; ++index) {
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(shakePath, NULL, CGRectGetMinX(frame) - frame.size.width * vigourOfShake, CGRectGetMinY(frame));

        CGPathAddLineToPoint(shakePath, NULL, CGRectGetMinX(frame) + frame.size.width * vigourOfShake, CGRectGetMinY(frame));
    }

    CGPathCloseSubpath(shakePath);

    shakeAnimation.path = shakePath;
    shakeAnimation.duration = durationOfShake;


    [lockView.layer addAnimation:shakeAnimation forKey:@"frameOrigin"];

}
```

Answer (score 206, accepted):

I wrote that post. It's overkill for a UIView, plus the parameters are geared toward an OSX app. Do this instead.

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = 
                         [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
[animation setDuration:0.05];
[animation setRepeatCount:8];
[animation setAutoreverses:YES];
[animation setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
               CGPointMake([lockView center].x - 20.0f, [lockView center].y)]];
[animation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
               CGPointMake([lockView center].x + 20.0f, [lockView center].y)]];
[[lockView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
```

You'll have to play with the duration and repeatCount parameters as well as the x distance from center in the from and to values, but it should give you what you need.

---

---

---

**Swift 3.0**

```
let midX = lockView.center.x
let midY = lockView.center.y

let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
animation.duration = 0.06
animation.repeatCount = 4
animation.autoreverses = true
animation.fromValue = CGPoint(x: midX - 10, y: midY)
animation.toValue = CGPoint(x: midX + 10, y: midY)
layer.add(animation, forKey: "position")
```

Comment: Thanks, i use your answer to build it in Xamarin IOS

If anyone would like to use it, here it is:
https://gist.github.com/jorwan/1ed57459c7b01b5a5b1135219e6219cf

Comment: @Matt What if I want to shake randomly, so the UIView moves at random directions on each shake?

Comment: @EhteshamHasan it couldn't be truly random. The positions/points would have to be within a range and you may not want it to shake between the extremes (corner to corner for example) of that range (though that's up to you). The simple answer is put the possible positions (CGPoints) in an array and seed a random number generator that provides an index less than the count of points in your array and then move the position to that point using the same technique described in my answer.

Answer (score 85):

I prefer this solution that has a nice springy behavior, ideal for a wrong-password shake animation.

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(20, 0);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0.0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.2 initialSpringVelocity:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
} completion:nil];
```

#### Swift 3

```
extension UIView {
    func shake() {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 20, y: 0)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you repeat this? it only happens once right now.

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, he wanted a short shake animation. Since in real life a shake movement has friction and slows down over time, I find my solution most appropriate. If you want to make it shake longer, experiment with the damping and initialVelocity parameters. If you want to repeat it indefinitely go with one of the other solutions.

Comment: this animation was the best, agreed. just want to repeat it a few times, that's all.

Comment: If you just want to extend it, try to play with the duration, damping and initialVelocity values.

Comment: I would add a completion block from this extension.

Comment: This solution is much better because of possibility to use completion handler.

Comment: I had good results replicating the standard iOS passcode screen shake using this code with a duration of 0.4, damping of 0.03, spring velocity of 1.2 and an initial X transform of 35.

Answer (score 35):

Here's my nice and simple looking version This simulates the shake you get on Mac OS X when you do an incorrect login. You could add this as a category on UIView if you like.

```
@implementation UIView (DUExtensions)

- (void) shake {
    CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x"];
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    animation.duration = 0.6;
    animation.values = @[ @(-20), @(20), @(-20), @(20), @(-10), @(10), @(-5), @(5), @(0) ];
    [self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"shake"];  
}

@end
```

The animation values are the x offset from the views current position. Positive values shifting the view to the right, and negative values to the left. By successively lowering them, you get a shake that naturally loses momentum. You can tweak these numbers if you like.

Comment: Great looks and sound idea to embed this into a UIView category. UIViews should shake, period!

Comment: When used at a slower speed (i.e. longer duration) this animation is much smoother than the one from the other answer that uses repeatCount.

Comment: Some thoughts after going to use this code. *Timing Function* - defaults to linear so not necessary to set it. *Animation Values* - you could go a step further and define a function to produce nice mathematical values... this works too though :)

Answer (score 17):

Here is the swift version as an extension in case anybody needs it

```
extension UIImageView{
    func vibrate(){
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        animation.duration = 0.05
        animation.repeatCount = 5
        animation.autoreverses = true
        animation.fromValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(self.center.x - 2.0, self.center.y))
        animation.toValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(self.center.x + 2.0, self.center.y))
        self.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "position")
    }
}
```

This will animate an small UIImageView (around 15x15). If you need to animate something bigger you may want to change the 2.0 factor of movement to something greater.

Answer (score 10):

Based on @bandejapaisa answer, UIView extension for Swift 3

```
extension UIView {
    func shake() {
        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.x")
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
        animation.duration = 0.6
        animation.values = [-20, 20, -20, 20, -10, 10, -5, 5, 0]
        layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "shake")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this piece of code:

to call the code below, use: `[self earthquake:myObject];`

```
#pragma mark EarthQuake Methods

- (void)earthquake:(UIView*)itemView
{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate); 

    CGFloat t = 2.0;

    CGAffineTransform leftQuake  = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, t, -t);
    CGAffineTransform rightQuake = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, -t, t);

    itemView.transform = leftQuake;  // starting point

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"earthquake" context:itemView];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES]; // important
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:3];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.05];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(earthquakeEnded:finished:context:)];

    itemView.transform = rightQuake; // end here & auto-reverse

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)earthquakeEnded:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context 
{
    if ([finished boolValue]) 
    {
        UIView* item = (UIView *)context;
        item.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can call this method on UIButton click event

```
-(void)shakescreen
{
    //Shake screen
    CGFloat t = 5.0;
    CGAffineTransform translateRight = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, t, t);
    CGAffineTransform translateLeft = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, -t, -t);

    self.view.transform = translateLeft;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.05 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse|UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^
    {
         [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:2.0];
         self.view.transform = translateRight;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished)

      {
          if (finished) 
          {
             [UIView animateWithDuration:0.05 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^
          {
              self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
          } 
          completion:NULL];
      }
  }];
}
```

Hope this will help you :-)

Answer (score 4):

C# Xamarin.iOS version of [answer how to create UIView shake animation in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17352449/883738) is below

```
        CAKeyFrameAnimation keyframeAnimation = CAKeyFrameAnimation.GetFromKeyPath(new NSString("transform.translation.x"));
        keyframeAnimation.TimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.FromName(CAMediaTimingFunction.EaseInEaseOut);
        keyframeAnimation.Duration = 0.6f;
        keyframeAnimation.Values = new NSObject[]{ new NSNumber(-20f), new NSNumber(20f), new NSNumber(-20f), new NSNumber(20f), new NSNumber(-10f), new NSNumber(10f), new NSNumber(-5f), new NSNumber(5f), new NSNumber(0f) };
        shakyView.Layer.AddAnimation(keyframeAnimation, "shake");
```

Answer (score 4):

> **@imike answer in Swift 4.2**

```
extension UIView {
func shake() {
    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.x")
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear)
    animation.duration = 0.6
    animation.values = [-20, 20, -20, 20, -10, 10, -5, 5, 0]
    self.layer.add(animation, forKey: "shake")
}}
```

Comment: Last line should be fixed with self.layer.add(animation, forKey: "shake")

Answer (score 2):

Here's one that uses a damper function to decay the shake:

```
- (void)shake
{
    CAKeyframeAnimation* animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    animation.duration = 0.5;
    animation.delegate = self;
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];

    NSMutableArray* values = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    int steps = 100;
    double position = 0;
    float e = 2.71;

    for (int t = 0; t < steps; t++)
    {
        position = 10 * pow(e, -0.022 * t) * sin(0.12 * t);
        NSValue* value = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake([self center].x - position, [self center].y)];
        DDLogInfo(@"Value: %@", value);
        [values addObject:value];
    }

    animation.values = values;
    [[self layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I refactored @Matt Long  code and made a category to `UIView`. Now it's much more reusable and easy to use.

```
@implementation UIView (Animation)

- (void)shakeViewWithOffest:(CGFloat)offset {
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
    [animation setDuration:0.05];
    [animation setRepeatCount:6];
    [animation setAutoreverses:YES];
    [animation setFromValue:@([self center].x-offset)];
    [animation setToValue:@([self center].x+offset)];

    [self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position.x"];
}

- (void)shake {
    [self shakeViewWithOffest:7.0f];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3 implementation based on @Mihael-Isaev answer

```
private enum Axis: StringLiteralType {
    case x = "x"
    case y = "y"
}

extension UIView {
    private func shake(on axis: Axis) {
        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.\(axis.rawValue)")
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
        animation.duration = 0.6
        animation.values = [-20, 20, -20, 20, -10, 10, -5, 5, 0]
        layer.add(animation, forKey: "shake")
    }
    func shakeOnXAxis() {
        self.shake(on: .x)
    }
    func shakeOnYAxis() {
        self.shake(on: .y)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4.0:

Based on the top answer but a refinement over the animation: This does not have the jumps at the start and end of animation.

```
    let midX = center.x
    let midY = center.y

    let rightAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.position))
    rightAnim.duration      = 0.07
    rightAnim.autoreverses  = true
    rightAnim.fromValue     = CGPoint(x: midX, y: midY)
    rightAnim.toValue       = CGPoint(x: midX + 9, y: midY)

    let leftAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.position))
    leftAnim.duration       = 0.07
    leftAnim.autoreverses   = true
    leftAnim.fromValue      = CGPoint(x: midX, y: midY)
    leftAnim.toValue        = CGPoint(x: midX - 9, y: midY)

    let group = CAAnimationGroup()
    group.duration      = leftAnim.duration + rightAnim.duration
    group.animations    = [rightAnim, leftAnim]
    group.repeatCount   = 3

    layer.add(group, forKey: #keyPath(CALayer.position))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

```
+ (void)vibrateView:(UIView*)view
{
    CABasicAnimation *shiverAnimationR;
    shiverAnimationR = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    shiverAnimationR.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(1)];
    //shiverAnimationR.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-10)];
    shiverAnimationR.duration = 0.1;
    shiverAnimationR.repeatCount = 1000000.0; // Use A high Value
    shiverAnimationR.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];

    [view.layer addAnimation: shiverAnimationR forKey:@"shiverAnimationR"];

    CABasicAnimation * shiverAnimationL;
    shiverAnimationL = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    //shiverAnimationL 2.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(10)];
    shiverAnimationL.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-1)];
    shiverAnimationL.duration = 0.1;
    shiverAnimationL.repeatCount = 1000000.0;
    shiverAnimationL.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];

    [view.layer addAnimation: shiverAnimationL forKey:@"shiverAnimationL"];

}
```

[From the link.](http://developmobilesoftware.blogspot.in/2013/09/vibrate-uiview-add-shivering-effect-to.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version using,

```
+ (void)animateKeyframesWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

Introduced in iOS 7.

```
    const CGFloat xDelta = 16.0f;

    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.50f
                                   delay:0.0f
                                 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeLinear
                              animations:^{

                                  [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0
                                                          relativeDuration:(1.0/6.0)
                                                                animations:^{
                                                                    self.passwordTextField.transform = self.usernameTextField.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(xDelta, 0.0);
                                                                }];

                                  [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:(1.0/6.0)
                                                          relativeDuration:(1.0/6.0)
                                                                animations:^{
                                                                    self.passwordTextField.transform = self.usernameTextField.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-xDelta, 0.0);
                                                                }];

                                  [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:(1.0/3.0)
                                                          relativeDuration:(1.0/3.0)
                                                                animations:^{
                                                                    self.passwordTextField.transform = self.usernameTextField.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(xDelta/2.0, 0.0);
                                                                }];

                                  [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:(2.0/3.0)
                                                          relativeDuration:(1.0/3.0)
                                                                animations:^{
                                                                    self.passwordTextField.transform = self.usernameTextField.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                                                                }];

                              }
                              completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a UIView extension providing an awesome shake animation: https://gist.github.com/mourad-brahim/cf0bfe9bec5f33a6ea66

A Swift5 update is provided on the comments.