# Animation on UIButton 

Tags: iphone, uibutton, core-animation, shake

I want to add animation to a button.when a button is touched it should shake for some duration. Then whatever method is linked with it should get call.

Comment: Could you define shake? Vertically, horizontally, both?

Answer (score 3):

Start with this for the animation:

[UIView shake animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844557/uiview-shake-animation)

Then implement [animationDidStop:finished:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) to perform some action when the animation has finished.

Best regards.