# Facebook iPhone app login effect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, effect

I can't find one term for explaining the effect that I would to achieve in my iPhone app.

If anyone have the Facebook app please open it and go to the login screen. Input only the username and press "Login". Did you see the textfield? It shakes.

Is there a way to define this effect and to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. You can achieve it with a CAKeyframeAnimation animation or a CABasicAnimation. Here are examples of both on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844557/uiview-shake-animation). The CABasicAnimation will be easier to implement.

Comment: This doesn't work, the method works but it doesn't work with UITextField.