# Facebook like login screen and validation(Window Shake Effect)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I need my login screen look like the following.

In `Facebooks` login, if you leave the username or password fields blank and click the Log in button, the `user name` and `password` fields vibrates (as in shakes).

How is this done ?

[image]

Comment: How do you think it's done? Set up some timers to move fields left for  some pixels and back and then to the right.

Comment: I need to know, if its a Cell or a Label used.

Comment: Looks just like a UITableView to me. Grouped, 2 rows, maybe with text fields as their views.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using `CABasicAnimation`. Take a look at this [UIView shake animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844557/uiview-shake-animation).

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = 
                         [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
[animation setDuration:0.05];
[animation setRepeatCount:8];
[animation setAutoreverses:YES];
[animation setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
               CGPointMake([lockView center].x - 20.0f, [lockView center].y)]];
[animation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
               CGPointMake([lockView center].x + 20.0f, [lockView center].y)]];
[[lockView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
```

for cocoa application take a look at [Core Animation Tutorial: Window Shake Effect](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/27/core-animation-tutorial-window-shake-effect/).

```
- (CAKeyframeAnimation *)shakeAnimation:(NSRect)frame
{
int numberOfShakes = 4;
float durationOfShake = 0.2f;
float vigourOfShake = 0.04f;
    CAKeyframeAnimation *shakeAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];

    CGMutablePathRef shakePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(shakePath, NULL, NSMinX(frame), NSMinY(frame));
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < numberOfShakes; ++index)
    {
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(shakePath, NULL, NSMinX(frame) - frame.size.width * vigourOfShake, NSMinY(frame));
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(shakePath, NULL, NSMinX(frame) + frame.size.width * vigourOfShake, NSMinY(frame));
    }
    CGPathCloseSubpath(shakePath);
    shakeAnimation.path = shakePath;
    shakeAnimation.duration = durationOfShake;
    return shakeAnimation;
}

    [window setAnimations:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[self shakeAnimation:[window frame]] forKey:@"frameOrigin"]];
    [[window animator] setFrameOrigin:[window frame].origin];
```