# UIWindow frame in ios 8 different from ios 7 in Landscape

Tags: ios7, ios8, xcode6, uiinterfaceorientation, uiwindow

I've create simple module where I add subview to UIWindow. In simulator ios 7(Xcode 5.1.1) I have printed self.windows and I get:

```
<UIWindow: 0x8db1670; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8db1a70>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x8db17d0>>
```

but on ios8 (Xcode 6 beta 6) I get:

```
<UIWindow: 0x794320d0; frame = (0 0; 1024 768); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x79437a80>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7943c400>>
```

The question is: why there is a difference in frame property?

Comment: have look here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150359/is-uiscreen-mainscreen-bounds-size-becoming-orientation-dependent-in-ios8

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably in your AppDelegate you initializing your UIWindow like this

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Prior to iOS8 the bounds property of UIScreen returned the bounding rectangle of the physical screen (that is, portrait), but starting from iOS8 bounds changes when the device rotates [documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/bounds)

You can now use nativeBounds instead if you'd like to get the bounding rectangle of the physical screen.

Note: nativeBounds returns the screen in pixels but bounds returns it in points.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this issue was just to ignore the:

```
CGAffineTransformMakeRotation
```

on iOS8 and now everything works for me! thanks :)

Comment: and how might you do that?

Comment: Not the most helpful of answers. Care to elaborate?