# How to handle the UIImageViews during tap event

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I am using UIImageview to display the image from saved library.Then, During UILongPressGestureRecognizer event , i insert the custom button to delete.before that in need to shake the pressed image.
please if any one help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to shake the UIImageView, which you can find plenty of examples for. For example this one, check the first answer:

[UIView shake animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844557/uiview-shake-animation)

Use your UIImageView instead of lockView.