# Trying to shake UIButton (that have constraints) by trying to change constraints etc but nothing happens?

Tags: ios, animation, uibutton

My button has a constraint that it should center horizontally in the superview. I tried to just change my constraint but nothing happens. My idea is that I move my button to the side and then back and add a springy automation.

```
- (void)shakeView {
    NSLog(@"Shake it baby!");
    NSUInteger centerDefault = self.loginButtonHorizontalCenterConstraint.constant;
    self.loginButtonHorizontalCenterConstraint.constant = centerDefault + 50;

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    //  self.signInContainerCenterPosition = constraint
    self.loginButtonHorizontalCenterConstraint.constant = centerDefault;

    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:0.0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.1 initialSpringVelocity:40 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{

        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {


    }];
}
```

So, I got two questions. Why can't I move my button to the side with 50px and is this a  viable way to get my uibutton to shake?

Comment: This question can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844557/uiview-shake-animation

Comment: Thanks but seen it and tried it. Nothing happen