# How to repeat shake animation indefinitely or X times using animateWithDuration?

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation, uiviewanimation

The code below came from this SO question: [UIView shake animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844557/uiview-shake-animation).

This shake animation is perfect, except it stops after one iteration. How do you repeat the animation indefinitely, or how do you cause it to repeat it X times?

There are other SO answers on repeating UIView animations that suggest using `CAKeyframeAnimation` or `CABasicAnimation`, but this question is different. The goal is to reproduce this exact animation, with the "springy" effect from `usingSpringWithDamping` and `initialSpringVelocity.`

Using Autoreverse and Repeat don't reproduce the desired effect because the the initial translation is outside the animation block.

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(20, 0);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0.0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.2 initialSpringVelocity:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
} completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need exact same code few times than put that code in method and do recursion, something like that:

```
- (void)animateCount:(NSInteger)count {
   if (count == 0) {
      return;
   }

   view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(20, 0);
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0.0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.2 initialSpringVelocity:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
      view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
   } completion:^{
      count--;
      [self animateCount:count];
   }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `(UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat)` in options to repeat it indefinitely

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0.0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.2 initialSpringVelocity:1.0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut) animations:^{

    someView.frame = someFrame1;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{

        someView.frame = someFrame2;

    } completion:nil];

}];
```